# ARcore to get photos with camera location (latitude, longitude, altitude) and orientation (pitch, yaw, roll) at fixed distance trigger

Tags: flutter, computer-vision, camera, arcore, pose

I am working with Google ARcore in a mobile app developed in Flutter.

The main thing I want to implement is a camera motion tracking while also triggering photos at a fixed distance (let say 15 cm) between one photo to the next one. Basically, at the end of my acquisition with the smartphone I need a set of photos with the geo-information of each of them (latitude, longitude, altitude, pitch, yaw, roll).

I have alredy implemented the ARcore Geospatial Pose to track the camera position (latitude, longitude, altitude) but I see that sometimes it does not work properly (some gps position are not correct and very far from the actual location). To furher improve the localization, I am asking if I need also other functions (e.g.: ArPose, ArAnchor) to increase accuracy of the VPS and if it is possible also to get the camera orientation (pitch, yaw, roll).

Thank you for your support!

Cheers,

Simon